# how to make footer rise with keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want footer to rise with keyboard when keyboard appear.

I tried adding code android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 ,android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
to manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/bt_cancel" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/tv_comment"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>

<Button
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I made the code simpler but I thought it's not good. So add raw code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/bt_cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btContribution"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/bt_contribution" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/tv_comment"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be on the right track, though I suspect the issue lies with the `LinearLayout` that exists as an immediate child of your `ScrollView`. I believe the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` attribute might be causing it not to work (I could be wrong!). That said, I tweaked your XML layout a little (I haven't had a chance to test it just yet) - would you be able to see if the below code works for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/bt_cancel" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="@string/tv_comment"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="255"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've had more success using `NestedScrollView` in the past. Please note that if you're not using `AndroidX`, you'll need to replace `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView` with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`.

Hopefully that helps - please let me know how you go!

Comment: Not a problem @fromjapan! If the solution that I’ve provided helped you out, do you mind accepting my answer?